# could not found jaeger distributed latency metrics of micro services in prometheus dashboard

Tags: apache-camel, prometheus, jaeger

We are using Jaeger with camel open tracing to get metrics, we are able to see all the latency metrics in Jaeger UI.

In Prometheus we are able to see few jaeger metrics request count, but the some metrics like latency we are not able to found in prometheus dashboard.

[Prometheus dashborad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xAOx.png)

We are exposing metrics using below:
host:14269/metrics, host:16687/metrics

Can some one help me to get the jaeger service latency metrics in prometheus.